# PIP install unable to find ffi.h even though it recognizes libffi

Tags: python, linux, pip

I have installed `libffi` on my Linux server as well as correctly set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable to the correct directory, as `pip` recognizes that it is installed; however, when trying to install pyOpenSSL, pip states that it cannot find file 'ffi.h'. I know both that`ffi.h` exists as well as its directory, so how do I go about closing this gap between `ffi.h` and `pip`?

Comment: if you are doing this to install scrappy, follow this tutorial https://clasense4.wordpress.com/2015/11/25/how-to-install-scrapy-on-centos-7/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `CFLAGS` (and `LDFLAGS` or various other compiler and linker options) in front of the `pip` command (ditto for `setup.py`):

Something similar to the following should work:

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/libffi/include pip install pyOpenSSL
```

Comment: This didn't work for me rather installing `libffi-dev` did.

Comment: this also fixed my failing pip3 install jupyter which gave an error compiling ffi.h on raspbian

Answer (score 272):

You need to install the development package as well.

`libffi-dev` on Debian/Ubuntu, `libffi-devel` on Redhat/Centos/Fedora.

Comment: Note that the OP states "I know both that ffi.h exists as well as its directory", indicating that the development √ersion (headers) is already installed. So this answer solves another problem.

Comment: `apk add libffi-dev` worked for me on Alpine 3.11.6. Thanks

Answer (score 26):

To add to mhawke's answer, usually the Debian/Ubuntu based systems are "-dev" rather than "-devel" for RPM based systems

So, for **Ubuntu** it will be `apt-get install libffi libffi-dev`

**RHEL, CentOS, Fedora (up to v22)** `yum install libffi libffi-devel`

**Fedora 23+** `dnf install libffi libffi-devel`

**OSX/MacOS** (assuming homebrew is installed) `brew install libffi`

Comment: For ubuntu it is libffi6 now.

Comment: @darkhipo - Note that the development library, i.e. libffi-dev is still named `libffi-dev` (without the 6). This is relevant for  11/2019 using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu/Mint

```
sudo apt-get install libffi6 libffi-dev
```

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: [ChrisN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38077173/712526) already covered this. If your answer adds additional value, please explain.

Answer (score 4):

`pip` packages usually don't use `pkg-config`. Therefore, you should set `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` manually:

```
CFLAGS=$(pkg-config --cflags libffi) LDFLAGS=$(pkg-config --libs libffi) pip install pyOpenSSL
```

Answer (score 4):

On Debian,

```sh
apt-get install libffi-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

on CentOS:

```
yum install libffi-devel
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of this existing answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508612/pip-install-unable-to-find-ffi-h-even-though-it-recognizes-libffi/31508663#31508663

Comment: Right @karel, I did not see that when I was writing the answer. I still want to keep it since somebody already has benefited from it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the development package for `libffi`.

On RPM based systems (Fedora, Redhat, CentOS etc) the package is named `libffi-devel`.

Not sure about Debian/Ubuntu systems, I'm sure someone else will pipe up with that.